# Why are my pygame images not getting the alpha set after changing from windows to mac

Tags: python, windows, macos, pygame, alpha

These are the parts of the code that are relevant:

```
class t_color(object):
    BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
    GREY = (128, 128, 128)
    GREEN = (0, 128, 0)
    LIME = (0, 255, 0)
    PURPLE = (128, 0, 128)
    RED = (255, 0, 0)
    SILVER = (192, 192, 192)
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

IMAGE_ALPHA = t_color.BLACK
...
img = pygame.image.load('images/' + str(i) + '.bmp')
img.set_colorkey(IMAGE_ALPHA)
g.images.append(img)
```

On windows this was working fine. Now that I'm using Mac (10.9) and python 2.7.5(on windows I had 2.7.6) pygame 1.9.2 (on windows I had 1.9.1)

Here are the images I'm useing, they are only 32x32 px: `http://www.mediafire.com/download/nf9exc8trged687/images.zip`

I want to set the black to be transparent as the images are BMP files and don't support transparency.

Does anyone know what is causing this or how to fix?

Comment: The image in `/other` is not being used for the alpha, It was just part of my game.

Comment: Works fine for me on linux using 1.9.1.

Comment: I know, it works fine for me on windows too, just not mac :\

Comment: Have you tried pygame version 1.9.1 on mac instead of 1.9.2?

Comment: Can't install 1.9.1, the installer says that i need python 2.7? even though I have 2.7.5. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13078080/3157252 -- Not mine, foudnd it

There's per-pixel alpha, colorkey alpha, and per-surface alpha. You're asking for colorkey.

When you call [`convert_alpha()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.convert_alpha) it creates a new surface for per-pixel alpha.

And from  [set_colorkey](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.set_colorkey)

> The colorkey will be ignored if the Surface is formatted to use per pixel alpha values.

So: Load image with `.convert()` Since you want to use a color key. Then call `set_colorkey`.

> Also, I saw nothing in the docs about passing "-1" as first argument to set_colorkey.

That's probably from a tutorial, which has a load_image function to grab the topleft pixel's color value.