# pygame.display.set_icon() not handling transparency too well

Tags: python, transparency

Yes, I know that there is another post asking this, but I tried the answer in that, and it didn't work, it just made it worse. Here are all the posts I've tried:

[PyGame: Applying transparency to an image with alpha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879225/pygame-applying-transparency-to-an-image-with-alpha)

[Pygame.display.set_icon unable to show transparecy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/104257/pygame-display-set-icon-unable-to-show-transparecy)

[How do I set a transparent icon?](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/261nu5/how_do_i_set_a_transparent_icon//)

And my result from trying to use transparency was WAY different than them. Here's my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Undertale")
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("icon.png").convert_alpha())
```

and here is the result:

[image]

Here is the original image:

[image]

Any help?

EDIT: I did what @user2588654 said:

> Given the above, my suggestion would be to try remaking the heart at 32x32 pixels with a white background without transparency and apply the colorkey. Let me know if this helps!

And here is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Undertale")
icon = pygame.image.load("icon.png")
icon.set_colorkey((0,255,0))
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
```

Here is the new icon.png:

[image]

And here is the result:

[image]

Although it isn't much, It's still a little annoying. If it's not possible to fix, that's fine, and if it is, then I'd like to know it.

Comment: Maybe duplicate with ["PyGame: Applying transparency to an image with alpha ?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879225/pygame-applying-transparency-to-an-image-with-alpha).

Comment: That's the one I mentioned in the post. I viewed it and it didn't work...

Comment: Ok, could you edit your question and add the link to that post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. When I ran it with your test heart image, I got the following test warning in my command prompt: `libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile`. Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747902/2588654), I converted it using image magick and that got rid of the error, but it still looked like your screenshot, so this is probably not too important.

According to the pygame documentation on this [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html) for `pygame.display.set_icon()`, it looks like most systems want a smaller image around **32x32** pixels. Resizing your image to that size removed most of the artifacts on the image, but this is not ideal since your heart is pixel art around 20x20 pixels. Furthermore, it looks like icons in pygame **do not support complete transparency**, but instead only support **colorkey**. That is, you basically choose a color to set as completely transparent by calling `surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))`, where `surf` refers to your icon image surface after `pygame.image.load("icon.png").convert_alpha()`. In my example, the tuple `(255, 255, 255)` refers to a white color.

Given the above, my suggestion would be to try remaking the heart at 32x32 pixels with a white background without transparency and apply the colorkey. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: It did help, but it is still a little glitchy. As said in my post, if there is no fix, then that's fine, but if there is, I'd like to know please.

Comment: Looking at the results in your question, it looks like pygame is linearly interpolating the RGB values of the adjacent pixels, resulting in those black spots. After looking at the documentation, I am not sure how to disable this unfortunately.

Comment: One idea I guess you can use to mitigate the issue is to add "antialiasing" to your drawing by adding dark red pixels along the borders of your heart to make it smoother. It still doesn't really solve the issue but makes the large black pixels slightly less obvious. This is really frustrating though...

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. Sorry for waiting so long for a reply. I'll just leave it be, as it's not too bothering anymore. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Windows: I was trying to use an 80x80 PNG image with transparency as my icon.

I tried the suggestions in CodeSurgeon's answer, and found that colorkey transparency did not actually make the icon background transparent in the taskbar on Windows 10.

After some experimenting, I found that all I needed to do to make it work was:

```
icon = pygame.image.load(ICON_FILENAME)
icon = pygame.transform.smoothscale(icon, (96, 96))
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
```

That is, I just needed to **resize the image to an allowed windows icon size**. I did not need to convert my image to have a colorkey background.